# Simplest way to build a script that will append content to a certain file, Windows or Linux for such tasks?

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, cmd

Currently I'm using Windows.

I need a script that opens a certain file and appends a string to it. The string itself has 5 - 10 lines.

The string appended depends upon given script arguments - some parts of the string are arguments themself, others are static.

I tried doing this with a .bat file in windows, but I didn't really feel like it was suited for the job. Seemed too complicated.

Can this be done easier in Linux? Or somehow practical in Windows? I don't want to write C/C++ programs for such a simple task, just because the operating system doesn't provide a simple way to build similar things.

Basicaly, I just want to know which tool should I use (on Windows and Linux) and whether it's easier to build on Windows or Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use cygwin in Windows and then do it via the cygwin shell as told by Ernest. bat files are horrible. Linux IMO is much much smarter and efficient than Windows, you should switch to it but If you really need to stick to Windows, install cygwin.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in a UNIX shell (Linux, Mac OS X) you can just say

```
echo $THE_STRING >> /the/file
```

to add the contents of the variable `THE_STRING` to the end of the file. Can't get much easier than that.

Comment: What about Windows. Bat files aren't the right way? I used cmd so far. I guess I'll try powershell. If that won't work, I'll switch to Linux...

Comment: @ennuikiller's suggestion of Ruby, Python, or Perl is an excellent one; all of these are available cross-platform.

Answer (score 0):

There are many cross-platform tools to do this, Ruby and Perl immediately come to mind.  On Linux this is a trivial one line program as Ernest pointed out.  I'm sure there is something similar in powershell to do this.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell sounds like a good solution - in it's simplest form:

```
Add-Content path_to_file "Content to add"
```

To add a multi-line string you could do this:

```
$string = @"
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
"@

$filename = c:\test.txt

Add-Content $filename $string
```

you could get the content to add from a file as well

```
$text_to_append = Get-Content C:\my_text_to_append.txt
Add-Content $filename $text_to_append
```

or use the pipeline:

```
Get-Content C:\my_text_to_append.txt | Add-Content $filename
```

Be careful with encoding though. Works fine with ANSI - Unicode can be funny.

Comment: BTW, PowerShell is installed by default on new version of Windows OS and can be installed on older versions